# Why don't baseball players get involved with the spectators when something good happens?

Tags: baseball

When soccer players celebrate a goal, many times they celebrate "with" the public.

Why do baseball players pretty much ignore the public when celebrating? Or even don't show much emotion when a good play occurs?

For example, when running the bases after a home run many times the batter will show no emotion and not respond to the crowd cheering.

Comment: *When soccer players celebrate a goal, many times they celebrate "with" the public.* No, not always. There are fences and nets in the baseball stadium especially around home plate, and first and third base. Where do you expect it to happen? If a player shows too much emotion and performs excessive home run ceremony after hitting a home run, he can expect a hit by pitch at the next bat. That's for sure.

Comment: I don't mean physically with the spectators. This rarely happens in soccer. I mean things like looking toward the spectators, making gestures toward the spectators, etc. You'll find that most soccer celebrations involve gestures toward the crowd: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=soccer+goal+celebrations

Comment: Many times players will take a curtain call and/or tip their cap.  What would you have them do?

Comment: @user1167442 Celebrate like soccer players?

Answer (score 5):

While browsing through the Major League Baseball rules I think I found a clue:

> **4.06 (3.09) No Fraternization** Players in uniform shall not address or mingle with spectators, nor sit in the stands before, during, or after
>   a game. No manager, coach or player shall address any spectator before
>   or during a game. Players of opposing teams shall not fraternize at
>   any time while in uniform.

Reference: [MLB Official Baseball Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf)

Comment: That's an interesting rule, and I don't think it's ever enforced (what's the punishment?), but I found that its origins probably have to do with avoiding the appearance of collusion for gambling. But like you said, this rule is just a clue; I don't think it really explains why baseball players don't engage the crowd in a general celebratory way (if you take that premise to even be true).